# error: iostream: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, include, g++

When I try to compile c++ code, my include statements don't seem to be working. I haven't been c++ programming on my computer in a while, but this has never happened before.

I made a minimal test script, and upon compiling (g++ infile.cpp -o outfile.out) I get: "error: iostream: No such file or directory"

The same problem happens for vector, string, and I'm guessing other libraries.

Why isn't g++ finding the appropriate libraries?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might have the path incorrect to the iostream header. It may lie in a subdirectory of the default location g++ uses to search for .h files. Try a search for the iostream.h file.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: `g++ -v` on the command line will display the various default locations g++ uses.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you somehow hosed your compiler.  You'll need to reinstall it or something.

A normal install wouldn't need search paths and you shouldn't be including `iostream.h` even though it probably exists (gcc's non-h headers include the .h headers).

This of course assumes your compiler version isn't like 20 years old.  If that's the case then `iostream` probably doesn't exist and `iostream.h` would be the correct header to include.  But you've got a difficult life if that's the case and you'd have to be seriously resistant to change to have a compiler that old.  My bet is that this just isn't the case.